# Percent calculation in pandas

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below table, I want to calculate percent as the output in pandas. Can anyone assist?

Here is the the imagine reproduced as a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( data = {'Doc_No':[10,10,20,20],
                           'Fault':[0,1,0,1],
                           'count':[41,1,24,1]})
```

Would like to group data by "Doc_No" and then derive the per cent of "Fault" / "count" * 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's is a way to do what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( data = {'Doc_No':[10,10,20,20],
                           'Fault':[0,1,0,1],
                           'count':[41,1,24,1]}).groupby('Doc_No').sum()

result = (df['Fault'] / 
          df['count'])*100
```